# Android scheduled files to server

Tags: android

Ok i know how to send a file to the server...What i am looking for is code which looks in a folder on the sd card and then sends all the text files in there and then deletes them..However it needs to keep looking in there until there is internet connection so that it completes the job, otherwise it keeps looking in there every 30 seconds..? hope i explained correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me you should build a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which does those operations.

```
public class UploadService extends Service {

    private WakeLock cpuLock;
    private WifiLock wifiLock;
    private UploadFilesTask task;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {       
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();       
        final PowerManager powerMgr = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        cpuLock = powerMgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_lock");
        cpuLock.acquire();      
        final WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wifiMgr.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "my_lock");
        wifiLock.acquire();     
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {   
        super.onStart(intent, startId); 
        if ( intent.hasExtra("start") && taskIsNotRunning() ) {
            task = new UploadFilesTask();
            task.execute(null);
            return;
        } 
    }   

    private boolean taskIsNotRunning() {
        return task == null || task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || task.isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        super.onDestroy();
        cpuLock.release();
        wifiLock.release();
    }

    private class UploadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        private String dirName;

        public  UploadFilesTask(String directoryName) {
            dirName = directoryName;
        }       

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {               
            final File uploadDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);
            final File filesToUpload[] = uploadDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File f) {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
                }
            });
            for ( File f : filesToUpload ) {
                            try {
                 // invoke your method for upload
                             f.delete();
                            } catch ( Exception e ) {};
            }
            return null;            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {       
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            stopSelf();
        }   
    }

}
```

Don't forget about putting service declaration into AndroidManifest.xml file.

You can launch the service with "boot complete" intent or directly from your activity.

> However it needs to keep looking in
>   there until there is internet
>   connection so that it completes the
>   job, otherwise it keeps looking in
>   there every 30 seconds..? hope i
>   explained correctly

Try to launch the service when wifi/3G internet connection appear. Your service can be triggered by [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) intent (You have to add intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml file).

Let me put some advice about background operations:

- add some rules to decrease the rate of service runs. In other case your battery will drain very quickly. Also consider [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).
- check battery level before upload ([BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html)).
- check if you are in roaming mode and if user is fine with that ([SystemSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)).

Comment: Wow this is complicated lol...Being a beginner im not even sure firstly how to call this service? and how do i get it to keep looking at it every 30seconds

Comment: also do i need to declare the PowerManager and wifi in the manifest file?

Comment: "how do i get it to keep looking at it every 30seconds" -> don't do that, it will drain battery. "also do i need to declare the PowerManager and wifi in the manifest file?" -> No.

Comment: The wifi and powermanger give me an issue, and im going to ask it to check every 1 hour or 30min